# How can I get uptime to a remote windows-based computer as a standard user?

Tags: windows, uptime

There are plentiful ways in obtain remote uptime.  However it seems every one I have tried, powershell, wmic, systeminfo etc all required elevated access.  Unfortunately running this as a privileged account is not possible in this circumstance.  Is there anything that can make this happen?

```
PS C:\Users\jweinraub> get-wmiobject -computername jsmith Win32_OperatingSystem | select LastBootUpTime
get-wmiobject : Access denied
At line:1 char:1
+ get-wmiobject -computername jsmith Win32_OperatingSystem | select ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], Managemen
   tException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.C
   ommands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

Comment: `get-wmiobject Win32_OperatingSystem | select LastBootUpTime` doesn't require admin rights

Comment: For remote hosts it gives access denied.  See original question added the error

Comment: If you're able to enable SNMP on the remote hosts first, you will likely be able to poll it without admin.  Most server monitoring solutions do this.